# asp.net core Web API: use Roles and RequiredScope concurrent

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a WebAPI with OAuth2 (Microsoft Identity) and I need to support 'Client Credential Flow' (for non-interactive driven clients, with Roles) as well as 'Autentication Credential Flow' (for human-interactive clients, with Scopes).

How can I make it run with either 'MyRole' or with 'MyScope'?
... when the controller basically looks like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "MyRole")]
[RequiredScope("MyScope")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

I work with .NET 6

Comment: Hi @user1470240, you can read [this official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-6.0)  and custom your own policy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Starting in version Microsoft.Identity.Web v1.25.1 you have the attribute RequiredScopeOrAppPermission

```
[RequiredScopeOrAppPermission(
           AcceptedScope = new[] { "Scope1","Scope2" },
           AcceptedAppPermission = new[] { "Role1","Role2" })]
```

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.resource.requiredscopeorapppermissionattribute?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Marvelous! I just discarded my propretiary authorization approach, upgraded to v1.25.1 and use know the new attribute - works like a charm. Thank you for that hint!

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Rena, I found solution.

1. Create a requirement and an authorization requirement handler:

```cs
public class ClaimsScopeOrRoleRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
    
public class ClaimsScopeOrRoleRequirementHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ClaimsScopeOrRoleRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ClaimsScopeOrRoleRequirement requirement)
    {
        var canPass = context.User.IsInRole("MyRole"))
            || context.User.HasClaim(y =>
                (y.Type == ClaimConstants.Scope || y.Type == ClaimConstants.Scp)
                && y.Value == "MyScope"));
    
        if (!canPass)
        {
            context.Fail(new AuthorizationFailureReason(this, $"User neither claims required scope nor role."));
        }
        else
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

2. Add a new authorization policy and a dependency singleton for the authorization requirement handler to the services (in Program.cs):

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new ClaimsScopeOrRoleRequirement());
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, ClaimsScopeOrRoleRequirementHandler>();
```

3. Decorate the controller with the `Authorize` attribute with the added policy

```cs
[Authorize("MyPolicy")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

So it works.